# Primefaces layout bug

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 3.0.M4 with JSF2. 
I created a page divided into some layout units. In one layout unit I have a selectOneMenu. When the page is rendered the select works just fine, but if I collapse the layout unit and restore it back, the select doesn't work anymore. I can see it, I click it but nothing happens.
Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Report it as a bug to the PF guys.

Comment: Nope, still not laying out correctly in 3.3.1.

Comment: @SteveTaylor I know I found a workaround for this problem back then, but I have to remember how... Anyway it's hard to believe that primefaces guys haven't solved this problem yet - obviously you can create an issue with this bug